# iOS – Facebook SDK, parsing results

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

In my `-request:didLoad:` delegate method I'm `NSLog`ing the results but I can't figure out what's the content?

It looks like result is an `NSArray` but what is inside it? how do I parse the data?

A sample of the log looks like this:

```
result: (
        {
        "fql_result_set" =         (
                        {
               uid2 = 1234567;
            },
                        {
                uid2 = 12345678;
            }
        );
        name = queryID;
    },
        {
        "fql_result_set" =         (
                        {
                "birthday_date" = "05/12/1987";
                name = "John Doe";
            },
                        {
                "birthday_date" = "03/01/1978";
                name = "Jane Doe";
            }
        );
        name = queryBirthday;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook iOS tutorial, in "Step 6: Using the Graph API", says

> Note that the server response will be in JSON string format. The SDK uses an open source JSON library https://github.com/stig/json-framework/ to parse the result. If a parsing error occurs, the SDK will callback request:didFailWithError: in your delegate.
>
> A successful request will callback request:didLoad: in your delegate. The result passed to your delegate can be an NSArray, if there are multiple results, or an NSDictionary if there is only a single result.

In your example, everything printed by NSLog inside "()" is part of an NSArray, while everything inside "{}" (which also have keys incidentally) is part of an NSDictionary and therefore accessible by key (name).

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, all 'responses' are JSON-Objects. To parse these, iOS 5 provides a class called NSJSONSerialization ([NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946))

You normally parse it as follows:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```